# how do I set return_value of a mocked class instance when I don't have access to the instance itself?

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

Suppose I have some function `A.foo()` that instantiates and uses an instance of `B`, calling the member function `bar` on it.

How can I set `return_value` on a mocked instance of `B` when I'm testing my `A` class, given that I don't have access to the instance of `B`? Maybe some code would illustrate this better:

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock
import pandas

class A:
    def foo(self):
        b = B()
        return b.bar()

class B:
    def bar():
        return 1

@unittest.mock.patch("__main__.B")
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self, MockB):
        
        MockB.bar.return_value = 2
        
        a = A()
        
        self.assertEqual(a.foo(), 2)

test_case = MyTestCase()
test_case.test_case_1()
```

This fails with;

```
AssertionError: <MagicMock name='B().bar()' id='140542513129176'> != 2
```

Apparently the line `MockB.bar.return_value = 2` didn't modify the return value of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just 1 mistake in your code. Replace this line:

```
MockB.bar.return_value = 2
```

To:

```
MockB.return_value.bar.return_value = 2
```

And it would work.

---

I assume the piece of code you pasted is just a toy example. If the class `A` and `B` lies on another file e.g. `src/somedir/somefile.py`, don't forget to patch the full path.

```
@unittest.mock.patch("src.somedir.somefile.B")
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```

---

**Update**

To further expand on this, you can see some usage in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch):

> ```py
> >>> class Class:
> ...     def method(self):
> ...         pass
> ...
> >>> with patch('__main__.Class') as MockClass:
> ...     instance = MockClass.return_value
> ...     instance.method.return_value = 'foo'
> ...     assert Class() is instance
> ...     assert Class().method() == 'foo'
> ...
> ```

So in your case:

- `MockB.bar.return_value` is like calling a static method e.g. `print(MockB.bar())`
- `MockB.return_value.bar.return_value` is like calling a class/instance method e.g. `print(MockB().bar())`

To visualize this:

```
import unittest.mock


class SomeClass:
    def method(self):
        return 1


@unittest.mock.patch("__main__.SomeClass")
def test_mock(mock_class):
    print(mock_class)
    print(mock_class.return_value)

    mock_class.method.return_value = -10
    mock_class.return_value.method.return_value = -20

    print(SomeClass.method())
    print(SomeClass().method())


test_mock()
```

```
$ python3 test_src.py 
<MagicMock name='SomeClass' id='140568144584128'>
<MagicMock name='SomeClass()' id='140568144785952'>
-10
-20
```

- As you can see, `mock_class.return_value` is the one used for instance operations such as `SomeClass().method()`.

Comment: Thanks I'm marking this as the answer. One question though; how do you know that the reason was to use `MockB.return_value.bar.return_value`? This is non-obvious to me. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I updated my answer with further explanation. I hope I made it clear :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not initiating the MockB. You can directly mock "**main**.B.bar":

```
@unittest.mock.patch("__main__.B.bar")
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_case_1(self, MockB):
        
        MockB.return_value = 2
        
        a = A()
        
        self.assertEqual(a.foo(), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this without `mock.patch`. Change the `foo` method to accept a factory for the dependency it should construct ([DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)).

```py
class A:
    def foo(self, b_factory: 'Callable[[], B]' = B):
        b = b_factory()
        return b.bar()

def normal_code():
    a = A()
    assert a.foo() == ...

def test():
    dummy_b = ...  # build a dummy object here however you like
    
    a = A()
    assert a.foo(b_factory=lambda: dummy_b) == 2
```

Comment: I agree this would work but it seems like something you'd do in statically typed languages like C++. I think the mocking approach is more "pythonic". Having said that, I'm not much of a python dev, but that's my hunch. +1